# Windows::Foundation::Collections::IMap<T,T> to std::unordered_map

Tags: c#, c++, managed-c++

I am calling a method from c# that has a parameter like this:

```
IMap<T *, T *> *upserts
```

I am trying to iterate over it in my .cpp and convert it to native type to pass along to native c++ framework, but this doesn't want to work.

```
unordered_map<T *, T *> map = static_cast<unordered_map<T *, T *>>(upserts);
```

This iterator works (i think...), but map cast above isn't working:

```
for (auto const& x : map)
{
    //x.first is the key
    //x.second is the value
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot cast.  If you need an unordered_map<> then you cannot do anything but create one and fill it from the IMap.

Comment: how do i iterate over the IMap and fill the newley created unordered_map?

Comment: IMap derives from `IIterable<IKeyValuePair>`.  Google "c++/cx iterate imap" for basic hits.